# How do I access the information in this dictionary? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift.  I am trying to make a simple `REST` call and access the data that is returned.  I am testing with the `Zippopotam` API, which returns city information based on zipcode.  I get the result from the `REST` call and put it into a dictionary:

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
            options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
```

Here is some of the data that prints out when I print the json:

```
{
    country = "United States";
    "country abbreviation" = US;
    places =     (
                {
            latitude = "40.5541";
            longitude = "-111.9539";
            "place name" = "South Jordan";
            state = Utah;
            "state abbreviation" = UT;
        }
    );
    "post code" = 84095;
}
```

First of all, is there a better way to access a key value pair than

```
json["post code"].text!
```

That seems so low level to get the information, but maybe that is the only way to do it in `Swift`.

Next, my `places` are a `tuple`.  When I access the `places`, I get the information in parentheses `( info ...)`.  How do I access the `state` in the first tuple?  I have tried `json["places"].0["state"]`, but that is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only has three basic types - arrays, dictionaries and strings.  These are mapped by `NSJSONSerialization` to `NSDictionary` (which is bridged to a Swift dictionary), `NSArray` (bridged to Swift array) and `NSString` (bridged to String).

The simplest way to access the data returned by `NSJSONSerialization` is to just read the dictionaries & arrays as you have.

In the case of 'places' it is an array of dictionaries so to get 'state' you can say

```
if let places=json["places"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    if (places.count > 0) {
        let place=places[0]
        let state=place["state"] as! String
    }
}
```

The "better" way is to take the JSON and use it create objects with appropriate properties.  Unfortunately unlike XML which can use a defined schema to automatically generate this 'parsing' code you have to do this yourself